# Spannable текст и ellipsize

Tags: java, android, xml

Возникла следующая проблема : Необходимо отобразить текст с Spannable вставкой в TextView в одну строку так, что бы был виден конец строки ( если она вся не помещается на экран).
В разметке это выглядит так:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_step_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_step_title"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:lines="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

Однако, видно только начало строки. Кто-то уже сталкивался с такой проблемой?
Спасибо!

Comment: показите Spannable